# Where do I find all community/wiki questions?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Okay, I am not even entirely sure what community questions or wiki questions or posts (or answers?) are, but I have heard about them and I get the sense, that they are some kind of posts that are contributed to by everyone and they are about topics that are deemed to be of help to everyone or maybe topics that are very common.

I tried going to help section but could not find anything about them.

So, is there any way to find all the community questions/posts/answers in one place?

And there seriously needs to be a section in help center explaining what these are and how they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Community wiki posts are explained in the help center [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) and on mother meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/263383).

The [search help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/searching) explains that you can filter any searches for community wiki posts by adding `wiki:yes` to your search, so searching for nothing else [returns a list of all community wiki posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes).

Comment: The help center explanation is buried under privileges . I think it would be really helpful to new users   , if it was under asking or answering heading. The mother meta one is really useful. I should have checked there first. And the wiki:yes thing was known to me , but i thought it was just for filtering the search results from among what we search. I did not know we could just use it to see ALL wiki posts. Glad to know. thank you